# set fix-antenna queue to discard FIX messages if there is an overload

Tags: c#, .net, fix-protocol

I am using .net core fix-antenna FIX message protocol engine - [here](https://github.com/epam/fix-antenna-net-core)

Is there a way to set the engine to ignore incoming FIX messages when the queue gets overloaded?